# NSRegularExpression Creation/Escaping Error

Tags: regex, cocoa-touch, nsregularexpression

I want to create the following regular expression with `NSRegularExpression`:
**+(,|.|\n|\s)**

One or more occurrences of any of these: comma, full stop (period), new line, whitespace.

I've attempted to create the `NSRegularExpression` as follows:

```
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"+(,|.|\\n|\\s)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

The important bit being:

```
regularExpressionWithPattern:@"+(,|.|\\n|\\s)"
```

From the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there is this information about escaping/quoting:

**Character Expression:** \

**Description:** Quotes the following character. Characters that must be quoted to be treated as literals are * ? + [ ( ) { } ^ $ | \ . /

So, I want the `.` to be treated as a literal. I've tried the following:

```
+(,|\.|\\n|\\s)
+(,|\\.|\\n|\\s)
```

None of the above work; all result in `nil` for `regex` with `NSCocoaErrorDomain` and `NSInvalidValue` in `error`.

Can anyone tell me how to create the regular expression that I want?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with nsregularexpression, but could it be that you have the quantifier `+` in the wrong place? In most implementations of Regex the quantifier is applied to a group/character by putting it afterwards: `(,|\\.|\\n|\\s)+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have the quantifier `+` in the wrong place. In most implementations of Regex the quantifier is applied to a group/character by putting it afterwards, like so:

```
(,|\\.|\\n|\\s)+
```

Comment: Thanks! First time I've used NSRegularExpression - but also (clearly) a long time since I've used regex in general ;)